# My website is generating too many redirects errors in chrome. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I wrote a game and put it online, and at the end of the game, there is a "restart" button. Rather than dealing with resetting the game state, I have it reload the page. However, after a few times of doing this, I get this screen in chrome:

[image: Redirect errors]

The reload code I'm using is:

```
<img id="restart-button" class="pointer" src="./img/restart.png"  onclick="location.reload()"/>
```

I'm also doing quite a lot of preloading for the game, I have 46 image/audio files that I load in the cache at the start of the game.

My best guesses are:

1. the "location.reload()" is actually loading it a ton of times
2. it doesn't like the amount of stuff I'm asking it to cache and re-cache

Do I need to redo this with a simple init function? That'd be a huge pain based on the way I wrote the game. what's going on here?

The url of the game is http://secretmommymakeover.com/

Comment: share the url of the game so we can see what the problem is,, it can be a ton of things

Comment: @KresimirPendic I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has DNS issue, not code related issues. That's good news for you :)

When I did `dig A secretmommymakeover.com` I get three IP addreses back, like this:

```
secretmommymakeover.com. 1725   IN  A   162.255.119.154
secretmommymakeover.com. 1724   IN  A   192.30.252.154
secretmommymakeover.com. 1724   IN  A   193.30.252.154
```

and that confuses the browser every n-th reload and tries to pull resourses or page from diff IP addresses...

Remove uncorrect IP address, and leave only correct one.

Also you have `www` subdomain redirect to and from naked domain name switched on, so try to switch if off if IP address didn't work.

[image]